# Java IndexOutOfBoundException

Tags: java

I'm trying to read from a text file, but I get this error I can't figure it out how to fix it .

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
```

and my code

```
try {
String scan;
FileReader file = new FileReader("C:\\Users\\W7\\workspace\\Lab 8\\students.txt");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(file);
while((scan = br.readLine()) != null) {
    String values = scan;
    String[] val = values.split("\t");
    String[] vals;
    vals = val[0].split(":");
    int size = val.length;
    System.out.println(vals[1]);
    switch (size) {
        case 3 :
        vals = val[0].split(":");
        int id = Integer.parseInt(vals[1]);
        vals = vals[1].split(":");
        String name = val[1];
        vals = val[2].split(":");
        int grade = Integer.parseInt(vals[1]);
        Student st = new Student(id, name, grade);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getStackTrace());
        }
```

My text file

```
ID:5    Name:john   Grade:6

ID:6    Name:paul   Grade:10
```

Comment: Which line is the error on?

Comment: I don't know. I get this error after I run the program

Comment: Does it give you a stack trace?

Comment: yes it gives trace which line

Comment: Post here a full stack trace

Comment: 1. are you sure your columns are separated by a tab (and not spaces)? 2. are you sure you don't have one or more tabs after the grade on one of the lines? 3. are you sure you don't have one more empty lines after Grade:10?

Comment: Also, please use `e.printStackTrace()` in the catch block to get informative stack traces.

Answer (score 2):

Length of `vals` is not known before accessing its first or second element:

```
String[] vals;
vals = val[0].split(":");
System.out.println(vals[1]);
```

Even before accessing the element at index 0, you need to make sure that vals is not an empty array by checking its length. This can happen, for example, when you encounter an empty line in the input which doesn't even have a tab.

Answer (score 1):

The error is where you use `vals[1]` before checking the length of `vals`.

```
vals = val.contains(":") ? val[0].split(":") : null;
int size = (vals == null) ? 0 : vals.length; // which is the array I think you want
System.out.println(vals[1]);
switch (size) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I think he wanted to do `size = vals.length;` anyway.

Comment: The code can fail at vals = val[0].split(":") too if the line doesn't have any tabs.

Comment: I fixed it. I only wanted to get the id,name,and grade(the values)

Answer (score 0):

```
                String values = scan;
                String[] val = values.split("\t");
                String[] vals;
                vals = val[0].split(":");
                int size = val.length;
                System.out.println(vals[1]);
```

You sure the codes above can handle a blank line? You are assuming every single line has at least 1 ":"